# JQuery popup dialog doesn't open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQueryUI 1.8.3. Trying to create a popup box that will later be submitted to the backend based on the dropdown selections.  Right now it just shows everything on the same page.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhoff/u0Lau81m/1/

```
$("#dialog").hide();
$("#target").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").show();
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
$("#submit").submit();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').ajaxForm(function () {
        window.close();
    });
});
```

Is something with my javascript incorrect?

Comment: Eventually I'm going to need to setup a request from the backend, just starting on it, still a work in progress.

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing some css-files (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)? A demo of your code in codepen seems to work fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJJwmR

Comment: That's possible, I had it working yesterday before I started on the ajax bit. I'll try that code editor for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use another jquery / jquery UI version. Updated Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0Lau81m/2/

```
$("#dialog").hide();
$("#target").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").show();
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
$("#submit").submit();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').ajaxForm(function () {
        window.close();
    });
});
```

greetings